# Column 'foreign_key_id' cannot be null

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-rest, quarkus

I have a rest api exposed via `@RepositoryRestResource` from `spring-data-rest-api`. When I try to give the json payload from Postman to create a User linked to an Organization, it complains that `Column 'organizationId' cannot be null`, when I clearly provided it in the json.

```
{
    "firstName": "Test",
    "lastName": "User",
    "email": "user@example.com",
    "phoneNumber": "+12019582790",
    "organizationId": "22bf93a5-e620-4aaf-8333-ad67391fb235",
    "password": "example123",
    "role": "admin",
}
```

Each user belongs to an organization, so it's a many to one relationship. I want Java to map the Organization that the User belongs to into the User as an Organization object.

**User.java**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User {

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Organization.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "organizationId", nullable = false)
    private Organization organization;
}
```

**Organization.java**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "organization")
public class Organization {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "id-generator")
    @Type(type = "uuid-char")
    @Column(name="organizationId")
    private UUID organizationId;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "organization")
    private Set<User> users;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi do you have getters/setters on the properties of `Organization` ? e.g. `setOrganizationId` and `getOrganizationId`? In your posted class there arent.

Comment: You have that in input payload, but do you set it inside your code to that column?

Comment: Yes I have getters and setters using lombok. When the payload hits the rest resource it should use the `organizationId` field to find the Organization by id and include it in the User, while persisting the UUID as the foreign key in my user table in mySQL.

Comment: Did you try modifying your JSON from `"organizationId": "22bf93a5-e620-4aaf-8333-ad67391fb235",` to `"organization": {"organizationId": "22bf93a5-e620-4aaf-8333-ad67391fb235"},` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the appoach I ended up going with. Still would like to know why the `@ManyToOne` annotation isn't saving the organizationId as a foreign key in the User table by itself.

**User.java**:

```java
@Type(type = "uuid-char")
@Column
private UUID organizationId;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "organizationId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Organization organization;
```